# Difference between LocalSessionFactoryBean in Hibernate 4 and AnnotationSessionFactoryBean in hibernate 3

Tags: spring, hibernate

In one project, we want to upgrade the hibernate version from 3.6 to 4.3.

in hibernate 3, we use AnnotationSessionFactoryBean:

```
 <bean id="AbstractSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        abstract="true">
    <!--  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.amazon.layout.dao.model" /> -->
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.amazon.layout.dao.model.EdgeModel</value>
            <value>com.amazon.layout.dao.model.VertexModel</value>
            <value>com.amazon.layout.dao.model.PhysicalResourceToVertexMappingModel</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Use Spring transactions for Hibernate -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" mode='aspectj' proxy-target-class='true' />
 </beans>
```

while in hibernate 4.3, we use LocalSessionFactoryBean:

```
 <bean id="AbstractSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        abstract="true">
    <!--  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.amazon.layout.dao.model" /> -->
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.amazon.layout.dao.model.EdgeModel</value>
            <value>com.amazon.layout.dao.model.VertexModel</value>
            <value>com.amazon.layout.dao.model.PhysicalResourceToVertexMappingModel</value>
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Use Spring transactions for Hibernate -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" mode='aspectj' proxy-target-class='true' />
</beans>
```

1. Are these two equivalent?
2. There is no exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory property in LocalSessionFactoryBean. is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the javadocs for `LocalSessionFactoryBean`:

> This class is similar in role to the same-named class in the orm.hibernate3 package. However, in practice, it is closer to AnnotationSessionFactoryBean since its core purpose is to bootstrap a SessionFactory from package scanning.

The reason the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` doesn't expose that method is that its unnecessary.

Comment: Can you explain more that why the property exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory is unnecessary to LocalSessionFactoryBean?

Comment: Because Spring automatically sets `CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS` with the `SpringSessionContext` where-as under Hibernate 3, it was configurable where a user could disable this functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Naros Can you explain... ts core purpose is to bootstrap a SessionFactory from package scanning. ?

Comment: @BhargavPatel You specify several properties when you define a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` such as _packagesToScan_, _annoatedClasses_, _annotatedPackages_, etc and the bean passes that information directly to Hibernate, allowing you to basically use the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` in much the same way you used the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` in legacy versions of Spring.